# How to confirm php enabled on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-http-server

I am not much into Linux. I am trying to setup a server through ssh. I installed apache php and mysql through this command.

```
sudo aptitude install apache2 php5-mysql libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server
```

but I think php is not enabled on the server.

When I run command I receive response as below

```
$ which apache2ctl
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl
```

But when I check `$ which php` I receive no response.

```
$ locate php5
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/php5
/usr/share/ubuntu-serverguide/html/C/php5.html
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On Debian (and thus Ubuntu), the Apache configuration files are stored under `/etc/apache2`.  In that directory, there are 2 sub-directories for configuring modules:  `mods-available` and `mods-enabled`.  When you install an Apache module (ie: foo), it will put `foo.load` (and possibly `foo.conf`) into the `/etc/apache2/mods-available` directory.  When you enable an Apache module using `a2enmod`, it will create a symbolic link in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` for each of the matching files from `/etc/apache2/mods-available`.

Thus for an Ubuntu server with PHP5 enabled, you should see something like this:

```
$ cd /etc/apache2
$ ls -l mods-*/*php*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 133 2008-02-27 15:49 mods-available/php5.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  59 2008-02-27 15:49 mods-available/php5.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  27 2009-02-05 07:30 mods-enabled/php5.conf -> ../mods-available/php5.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  27 2009-02-05 07:30 mods-enabled/php5.load -> ../mods-available/php5.load
```

If the php5 configuration files aren't shown in the `mods-enabled` directory, enable them as follows:

```
$ sudo a2enmod php5
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Once you've done that, in order to test that PHP5 is configured, create `/var/www/test.php` as follows:

```
$ echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" | sudo tee /var/www/test.php
$ sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/test.php
$ sudo chmod 755 /var/www/test.php
```

Once that's done, you should be able to browse to `/test.php` on that server and see the PHP configuration data.

Comment: I am getting permission denied for this line `$ sudo echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/test.php`.

Comment: @151291, try `echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" | sudo tee /var/www/test.php` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) function. Create a .php file that Apache will serve up and include the following:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

When you navigate to the .php file, and php is installed, it should give you a whole lot of information about the php version you have installed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the php binary is part of a separate package called php5-cli which you don't seem to have installed.

Comment: This is correct, but just to clarify: php5-cli is the commandline version, which you don't need if you're using it with apache.

Answer (score 1):

In aptitude do `/^php5$` and see if you have that package. If not, install it - that's the core package.

Comment: any command line that covers all php5 with cgi and so.?

Comment: Do you have the `php5` package installed?

Comment: yes it has [i] in front of them

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: What does `which php5` return? Did you try making a .php page with `phpinfo();`? Did you enable your site with `a2ensite`?

Comment: `which php5` returns no response, can you please help me over im? my yahoo id todi_shish. This is the first time I am setting up a server.

Comment: I don't have Yahoo but AIM - did you `sudo apache2ctl graceful` or `sudo apache2ctl restart` yet?

Comment: my aim shishant18 i restarted the apache server.

Comment: so you got it? what was it specifically?

Answer (score 1):

`a2dismod` disable apache modules and when executed without arguments displays the list of enabled modules:

> Your choices are: alias auth_basic authn_file authz_default
>   authz_groupfile authz_host authz_user autoindex cgi deflate
>   dir env mime mod-evasive mod-security negotiation **php5** 
>   rewrite scgi setenvif ssl status unique_id
>
> Which module(s) do you want to disable (wildcards ok)?

if `php5` is in the list it's installed and enabled. (CTRL-C to discard the command)

Answer (score 0):

Request the following URI from your server:

```
/?=PHPE9568F34-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42
```

You should get the PHP logo. If you do, PHP is working

Comment: No i am not getting any response

Comment: not working on my ubuntu with php enabled..

Comment: That URI only works if the root page is interpreted by PHP; if the URI isn't processed by PHP, nothing will happen.